# What is the extent of the CSF system out of the brain?

Tags: brain, spine

Does it spread sideways from the spinal cord at all?

How far down does it go?

I've found a lot of information about the spinal cord itself but not about the central canal, and more specifically if it's all there is to CSF out of the brain, or if there are small canals exiting it.